# Route(URL) error for each controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to **ASP.Net MVC 4**. I have **2 controllers**

- Customer
- Supplier

each controller have a menu **CustomerSetup** and **SupplierSetup**.

The first visited menu is ok, e.g when i click on **CustomerSetup Menu**, url looks like **localhost:1496/Customer/Index** its ok, now when i click on **Supplier Menu**, url looks like **localhost:1496/Customer/Supplier/Index** instead of **localhost:1496/Supplier/Index** and below error is shown..

**Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.**

Comment: You need to show how you generated the html for the links (looks like your not using `@Html.ActionLink()` and trying to hard code it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because you're using hand-coded URL to point to your `Supplier.Index` action. You better use the `Url.Action()` method instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Supplier")">Supplier Menu</a>
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think using html helper can help:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Menu name(display to user)","Action_name","Controller_name")
```

This will take you to your desired controller action.
eg:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home")
```